# Is there any way I can improve my interrupted time series analysis on this data?

Tags: regression, time-series, arima, nonlinear-regression, intervention-analysis

I ran a simple ordinary least squares (OLS) model of the form

y = b_0 + b_1 * T + b_2 * D + b_3 * P + e

where y is the number of murders in a given month, T is the number of months passed from the start of the study, D is a dummy variable indicating whether the observation was before or after an intervention (in this case the start of the Covid-19 pandemic), and P is the number of months since the start of the intervention. D can be interpreted as the level change of the observations after the intervention and P can be interpreted as the change in trend. e represents the residuals.

In doing so, I obtained the following results:

[image]
[image]

The R^2 value is somewhat low, suggesting a not-so-great model fit. However, all of the coefficients were significant.

I also compared an ARIMA (1,0,0) as well as a SARIMA (1,0,0),(1,0,0,12) but the AIC values were similar to that of the OLS regression. Both ARIMA and SARIMA models were almost identical. Here are the results for the ARIMA model.

[image]
[image]

I don't really think the ARIMA and SARIMA models are a much better fit than the OLS. The variance of the murder counts seem quite high and I guess I probably only have weak predictors that inadequately capture that variation. However, I was wondering if there was still any way I could improve my model analysis?